# How to use user variable as counter with inner join queries that contains GROUP BY statement?

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have 2 tables `odds` and `matches` :

matches : has `match_id` and `match_date`

odds : has `id`, `timestamp`, `result`, `odd_value`, `user_id`, `match_id`

I had a query that get the following information from those tables for each user:

1. winnings : the winning bets for each user. (when odds.result = 1)
2. loses : the lost bets for each user.(when odds.result != 1)
3. points : the points of each user.(the sum of the odds.odd_value) for each user.
4. **bonus : for each continuous 5 winnings i want to add extra bonus to this variable. (for each user)**

**How to calculate bonus?
I tried to use this query and I faced a problem :** (you can check it here [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b0741))

the calculated bonus are not right for all the users :

first user:(winnings:13, bonus=2).

second user:(winnings:8, bonus=2)bonus here should be 1.

third user:(winnings:14, bonus=3)bonus here should be 2.

why does the query not calculate the `bonus` correctly?

```
        select  d.user_id,
        sum(case when d.result = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as winnings, 
        sum(case when d.result = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as loses,
        sum(case when d.result = 1 then d.odd_value else 0 end) as points,
        f.bonus
FROM odds d
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT  
            user_id,SUM(CASE WHEN F1=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bonus
        FROM
        (
          SELECT 
            user_id,
            CASE WHEN result=1 and @counter<5 THEN @counter:=@counter+1 WHEN result=1 and @counter=5 THEN @counter:=1 ELSE @counter:=0 END AS F1
          FROM odds o
          cross join (SELECT @counter:=0) AS t
          INNER JOIN matches mc on mc.match_id = o.match_id
           WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(mc.match_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 2 AND 
                  YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(mc.match_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) =  2015 AND
                  (YEAR(o.timestamp)=2015 AND MONTH(o.timestamp) = 02)            
        ) Temp
        group by user_id
        )as f on f.user_id = d.user_id
      group by d.user_id
```

Comment: "add 0.5 to bonus for each winning value " -- you have nothing called `bonus` in your query.  Sample data and desired results might help clarify what you want to do.

Comment: @Strawberry it is not missing !!! the link is working

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added some samples and I made some changes can you check it now please

Comment: excuse me, I don't get the formula for bonus, could you axplain more detailed how do you calculate bonus for use id=100 and for user id=200  please it will help a lot

Comment: @Alex for each `(1,1,1,1,1)` streak I add 1 to bonus variable and that is grouped by user_id , after this streak I should make the `counter` (the temp variable) zero to start calculate the new streak.

Comment: can't load your sqlfiddle anymore :-(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your result related to `matches` table,

you can add back `WHERE` / `INNER JOIN` clause if you need.

Here is [link to fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/847dbb/1)

and the [last iteration](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2f207/5) according to your comments:

And here is a query:

```
SET @user:=0;

select  d.user_id,
        sum(case when d.result = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as winnings, 
        sum(case when d.result = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as loses,
        sum(case when d.result = 1 then d.odd_value else 0 end) as points,
        f.bonus
FROM odds d
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT  
            user_id,SUM(bonus) AS bonus
        FROM
        (
          SELECT 
            user_id,
            CASE WHEN result=1 and @counter<5 AND @user=user_id THEN @counter:=@counter+1 

                 WHEN result=1 and @counter=5 AND @user=user_id THEN @counter:=1 

                 WHEN result=1 and @user<>user_id THEN @counter:=1 
                 ELSE 
                 @counter:=0 
            END AS F1,
            @user:=user_id,
            CASE WHEN @counter=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bonus 
          FROM odds o
          ORDER BY user_id , match_id         
        ) Temp
        group by user_id
        )as f on f.user_id = d.user_id
      group by d.user_id
```

Comment: that is actually a wrong answer because I do not want to make the counter zero when the user_id changes . and you make it zero when the user changes.
for example maybe a streak for some user could be interrupted by another record for another user . that should not make the counter zero ,it should still calculating the same streak for that user because it has not face a lost result it is just interrupted with another user's winning result.

Comment: I hope it works : sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2f207/2 
if  a streak interrupted with `result=2` the counter does not go back to zero

Comment: I don't see anything wrong . You just not using my suggestion ORDER BY again. so here is your fiddle with order . http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2f207/3  what result is wrong? and why?

Comment: if you need other order try http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2f207/5  I just added `ORDER BY user_id, match_id` all bonuses are `=1` for data you provide. Is that was your goal?

Comment: my dear friend if you check the result values in the link that you provided for `user_id=300` you will find them like this `(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)` with this values the `bonus` should be `1` (because the first 4 1s interrupted with 2 so the counter will be zero then after this `2` the counter will start the counting again until it becomes 5 then the `bonus` will be 1 and the counter will go back to zero and will start again it will count until four so it will not add another 1 to the `bonus`) but in the link it gives the `bonus` value equals to  `2`

Comment: check the last link I gave, and try to understand the logic of query. you can manipulate with this as you wish. I am not your mom to fix any problem you have.  you didn't explain properly your requirements when post your question. and I still see how difficult for you to get help. It looks like I am forcing you to get it. As your mom was forcing you to go to school every morning. You should be able to manage your code and your life and try to get help people provide to you ;-)