# How to get right results from a query with user variable as a counter?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have this table called results :

```
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
| id | result | user_id | odd_value |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 |     100 | 2.5       |
|  2 |      1 |     100 | 2         |
|  3 |      1 |     100 | 1         |
|  4 |      1 |     100 | 3         |
|  5 |      1 |     100 | 1         |
|  6 |      1 |     100 | 2.1       |
|  7 |      1 |     100 | 3.5       |
|  8 |      1 |     100 | 1.8       |
|  9 |      1 |     100 | 1.6       |
| 10 |      1 |     100 | 2.5       |
| 11 |      1 |     100 | 1.8       |
| 12 |      1 |     100 | 1.2       |
| 13 |      1 |     100 | 2.2       |
| 14 |      1 |     200 | 3         |
| 15 |      1 |     200 | 4.1       |
| 16 |      1 |     200 | 2.5       |
| 17 |      1 |     200 | 1.5       |
| 18 |      1 |     200 | 1.2       |
| 19 |      1 |     200 | 6         |
| 20 |      1 |     200 | 3.1       |
| 21 |      1 |     200 | 2.9       |
| 22 |      1 |     300 | 2.2       |
| 23 |      1 |     300 | 2         |
| 24 |      1 |     300 | 3         |
| 25 |      1 |     300 | 2.1       |
| 26 |      1 |     300 | 2.7       |
| 27 |      1 |     300 | 2.3       |
| 28 |      1 |     300 | 2.1       |
| 29 |      1 |     300 | 3         |
| 30 |      1 |     300 | 3.4       |
| 31 |      1 |     300 | 2.1       |
| 32 |      1 |     300 | 1.7       |
| 33 |      1 |     300 | 3         |
| 34 |      1 |     300 | 4.2       |
| 35 |      1 |     300 | 2.2       |
+----+--------+---------+-----------+
```

I get some information from this table using this query :

```
SELECT  
            user_id,SUM(CASE WHEN F1=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bonus
        FROM
        (
          SELECT 
            user_id,
            CASE WHEN result=1 and @counter<5 THEN @counter:=@counter+1 WHEN result=1 and @counter=5 THEN @counter:=1 ELSE @counter:=0 END AS F1
          FROM odds o
          cross join (SELECT @counter:=0) AS t          
        ) Temp

group by user_id
```

I use the previous query to add 1 to the bonus variable for each five continuous winnings (win means result=1).
so for each streak (1,1,1,1,1) i add one to the `bonus` variable and then I grouped them by `user_id` to get the `bonus` for each user.

I get this result of the query and the data above:

```
+---------+-------+
| user_id | bonus |
+---------+-------+
|     100 |     2 |
|     200 |     2 |
|     300 |     3 |
+---------+-------+
```

and those are wrong results for `user_id=200` and `user_id=300` because :

for user_id = 200 there are just 8 winnings so the bonus should be 1 (because it has just one streak).

for user_id = 300 there are just 14 winnings so the bonus should be 2 (because it has just tow streak).

Comment: I already gave you an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28745212/4421474

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use user variable as counter with inner join queries that contains GROUP BY statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28674647/how-to-use-user-variable-as-counter-with-inner-join-queries-that-contains-group)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your result related to `matches` table,

you can add back `WHERE` / `INNER JOIN` clause if you need.

Here is [link to fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/847dbb/1)

And here is a query:

```
SET @user:=0;

select  d.user_id,
        sum(case when d.result = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as winnings, 
        sum(case when d.result = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as loses,
        sum(case when d.result = 1 then d.odd_value else 0 end) as points,
        f.bonus
FROM odds d
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT  
            user_id,SUM(bonus) AS bonus
        FROM
        (
          SELECT 
            user_id,
            CASE WHEN result=1 and @counter<5 AND @user=user_id THEN @counter:=@counter+1 

                 WHEN result=1 and @counter=5 AND @user=user_id THEN @counter:=1 

                 WHEN result=1 and @user<>user_id THEN @counter:=1 
                 ELSE 
                 @counter:=0 
            END AS F1,
            @user:=user_id,
            CASE WHEN @counter=5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bonus 
          FROM odds o
          ORDER BY user_id          
        ) Temp
        group by user_id
        )as f on f.user_id = d.user_id
      group by d.user_id
```

Comment: that is actually a wrong answer because I do not want to make the counter zero when the user_id changes . and you make it zero when the user changes.
for example maybe a streak for some user could be interrupted by another record for another user . that should not make the counter zero ,it should still calculating the same streak for that user because it has not face a lost result it is just interrupted with another user's winning result.

Comment: the only thing you need to add to the query is `ORDER BY user_id`

Comment: @BaselShbeb check updated answer and updated fiddle. that works even if I mixed data with user id=200 among user id=100

Comment: I tried to add order by user_id and also i tried your update, now it does not make the counter zero if the user changes but it will produce another problem if I use the order by user_id the query will not see the `result =2`.
If you change some of the result in the fiddle to 2 it will not break the streak .

Comment: What are you talking about? just click on my sqlfiddle link - everything is fine. If you have another fiddle with some special unique data - send it to me - then we can discuss what you are doing wrong.

Comment: can you change some of the values of the `result` field in `odds` table from `1` to `2`. It will give you wrong results for bonus.
so I think there is something wrong in else statement in the query , it does not break the streak if there is (losing value) `result=2`

Comment: do it yourself in sql fiddle, and provide me the link, and tell me what is your expected result, I will debug. By the way, it seems you are trying to argue with me but not to get help. If you don't need help - I can stop. Stackoverflow It is not the arena to fight. It is the place where developers helps each other ;-)

Comment: I hope it works : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2f207/2

And I am sorry if understand me wrong I do not fight . I am so grateful for your help